# How to override the [dir="rtl"] css selector?

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS rule:

```
[dir="rtl"] .navbar-toggle {
  float: left;
  margin: 15px 10px 0 0;
}
```

I need to override it to change the float and the margin values. I tried using the `:dir(rtl) {}` selector but it didn't work.

Any ideas guys?

**Note:** I prefer not to use the `!important` statement.

Comment: can you declare your overrides *after* this one?

Comment: Yes sure @DanielA.White

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase your selector combination [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity):

```
[dir="rtl"] div.navbar-toggle {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
}
[dir="rtl"] .navbar-toggle {
    float: left;
    margin: 15px 10px 0 0;
}
```